# Select last inserted elements containing tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I've been struggling to get a set of data from PostgreSQL for quite some time now.

I am using PostgreSQL 11 in Docker with the table `events` containing:

```
  Column   |    type   |   Modifiers
-----------|-----------|-------------
id         | text      | primary key
client_id  | text      | foreign key
created_at | timestamp | not null
context    | []text    | not null
```

The goal is to get the last inserted event for a subset of client_id along with a subset of context. Performance matters a lot, so I want to use SQL only.

So far, I explored a solution using `LATERAL` but it is not working fine:

```sql
SELECT e2.*
FROM (
    SELECT events.client_id, events.context
    FROM events
    WHERE 
        events.client_id IN (?) AND
        events.context && ?
    GROUP BY (events.client_id, events.context)
) e1 LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE 
        events.client_id = e1.client_id AND
        events.context = e1.context
    ORDER BY events.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
) e2 ON true;
```

The main problem with this is that when a given context literal is present in a two different contexts, this query will return both event but I only want one. I want `N` row per `client_id` where `N` is between 0 (no events) and the length of the given contexts in parameters.

---

Example with those rows :

```
created_at      |  client_id   |  context
----------------| -------------|------------
5pm:15          |     accb     |  ['home']
5pm:15          |     baac     |  ['home']
5pm:20          |     accb     |  ['home','shopping_cart']
5pm:25          |     accb     |  ['shopping_cart','payment']
5pm:30          |     accb     |  ['disconnect']
5pm:30          |     baac     |  ['home','shopping_cart','payment']
5pm:35          |     baac     |  ['disconnect']
```

With parameters `['accb','baac']` for client ids and `['home','shopping_cart']` for contexts, I want as a result :

```
created_at      |  client_id   |  context
----------------| -------------|------------
5pm:20          |     accb     |  ['home','shopping_cart']
5pm:25          |     accb     |  ['shopping_cart','payment']
5pm:30          |     baac     |  ['home','shopping_cart','payment']
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: How to identify the row you want to get for each literal in context? E.g. if you have two rows with contexts `['home', 'shopping_cart']` and `['home', 'shopping_cart', 'payment']` and your filter is `['shopping_cart', 'home']` which one shoul be returned? The question is unclear.

Comment: I want the most recent `events` row for every `client_id` and every `context` given in parameters. Both parameters are arrays. 
If two events contain ['home', 'shopping_cart'] and ['home', 'shopping_cart', 'payment'] with ['shopping_cart', 'home'] in parameter, I want the most recent of those two

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per `client_id`, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (e.client_id) e.*
from events e
where e.client_id in (?) and
      e.context && ?
order by e.client_id, e.created_at desc;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I edited my post so you can get a more comprehensible explanation

Answer (score 0):

A colleague found a solution :

```
WITH ranked_events AS (
    SELECT
        events.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS pos
    FROM
        events
    WHERE
        context @> ? AND
        client_id IN (?)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ranked_events
WHERE
    pos = 1
```